# Cannot move file after long running task

Tags: powershell

I have a windows powershell script executed by Windows Task Scheduler.  The powershell code starts an executable cli program (java), which creates it's own logfile, then when finished my powershell script tries to rename the file then upload it to a remote server.  However, I'm finding that it only successfully uploads the file ever 3rd or 4th execution and am not sure why.  The history in task scheduler provides no details as to what might have happened (file lock?).  Any ideas on how I can solve this?  Here is a basic example of what I'm doing:

```
$old_log_name = "old_logfilename"
$new_log_name = "new_logfilename"
C:\path\to\my-java-program.exe -pass -some -options
Move-Item -Path $old_log_name -Destination $new_log_name
gsutil cp $new_log_name gs://cool-bucket-with-cf
```

I'm certain that the problem is with renaming the file, and not with uploading it, because can see so in windows file explorer.
Should I be checking to see if the file is available to be renamed or not?

Edit (revised code based on comments below):

```
$app_version = "4.5.7"
$now = get-date
$now = $now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmm")
$old_log_name = "D:\myapp_$app_version.log"
$new_log_name = "D:\myapp_servername_$app_version.$now.log"
$arguments = "-a -c C:\myapp\config\Stage-$app_version.xml"
Start-Process C:\myapp\bin\4.5.7\myapp.exe -ArgumentList $arguments -NoNewWindow -Wait
Move-Item -Path $old_log_name -Destination $new_log_name
gsutil cp $new_log_name gs://path-to-mybucket
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you start a process with your java program, so it wait for it to exit ?

```bsh
$old_log_name = "old_logfilename"
$new_log_name = "new_logfilename"
Start-Process C:\path\to\my-java-program.exe -ArgumentList "your options" -NoNewWindow -Wait
Move-Item -Path $old_log_name -Destination $new_log_name
gsutil cp $new_log_name gs://cool-bucket-with-cf
```

**Update**
Since this is a scheduled task, you need to add a new event log in order to log events from your script (you need administrative rights for this) :

```bsh
New-EventLog -LogName Application -Source TheScriptThatCallsMyJavaProgram
```

Then, replace `Start-Process` call with the following (`EventId` is random here) :

```bsh
Write-EventLog -LogName Application -Source TheScriptThatCallsMyJavaProgram -EventId 3001 -Message "my-java-program.exe is about to start" # This logs the start of the program
$pinfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
$pinfo.FileName = "C:\path\to\my-java-program.exe"
$pinfo.Arguments = "your options"
$p = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
$p.StartInfo = $pinfo
$p.Start() | Out-Null
$p.WaitForExit()
Write-EventLog -LogName Application -Source TheScriptThatCallsMyJavaProgram -EventId 3002 -Message "my-java-program.exe is exited" # This logs the end of the program
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll give that a shot!  Powershell is not my forte, so much appreciated.

Comment: Hmm well that didn't work, I can see some files are still not getting renamed upon completion of the java process.  Is it possible the OS is still writing to the file when the process exits?

Comment: @Michael are you sure that the `my-java-program.exe` process is exited when `Move-Item` was executed (you can check by adding `Write-Host` before and after `Start-Process`) ? Also, I have the impression that the code you shared isn't the full story, if so can you please share your hole script or program (check https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: There's a little more but not much, just some code to manage the log filename.  I added an edit to show the full code example.  And no, I'm not sure the program is exited.  What exactly are you suggesting I do with Write-Host - just write some arbitrary data or something specific to check the state of the process?

Comment: Also curious, will data from Write-Host appear in the windows event log?  This is all executed by a scheduled task, so I have limited visibility for investigating what happened.

Comment: @Michael `Write-Host` won't log events in Windows event log. I updated my answer with a new solution that should work for you

Comment: Thanks again for the feedback, much appreciated.  It's been a little dicy getting this to work.  Was able to create a new event type to get my own events loading into the Application log, and also learned that I can use $? to determine if the attempt to move the file succeeded.  This prompted me to create a DO UNTIL loop with a 5 second sleep inside it.  Since creating that loop the system hasn't actually entered the loop recursively, so am now waiting to see if it works when the rename fails.

Comment: @Michael Glad to hear that, please mark my answer as the correct answer if it helped you solve your problem.

Comment: @Michael can you edit your question and share your code ?